# How does the model.predict() function work?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I am currently new to ML, and while going through one of the tutorials, I came across the model.predict() function. I have looked through the documentation of this function, but I want to know more about it, like how it works, the algorithm which it uses for prediction, etc. 
Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2):

For a neural network based model, predict() performs *forward propagation*. It is describes in many books and blogs. See for instance this introduction, https://towardsdatascience.com/coding-neural-network-forward-propagation-and-backpropagtion-ccf8cf369f76

Convolutional Neural Networks and Recurrent Neural Networks use layers which have slight different forward functions.